# Stored procedure cannot create complex type in entity framework

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I have added this store procedure through phpmyadmin:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `SelectUser`()
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
NO SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT ''
Select * from User
```

In my edmx but when create a complex type and do the Get column information that gives

> The store procedure returns no columns

Comment: Have you try to specify colums? i mean change your `*` to colunm enumeration?

Comment: yes,that also try it.

Answer (score 3):

try add
`SET FMTONLY OFF`in your sql statement

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more in detail why this should help?